# Does this converge? $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{n+ \log(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This seems too easy, my friend said he couldn't get it. maybe I am wrong??

$$\sum \limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{n+ \log(n)} \leq \frac1{n+n}=\frac1{2n} \leq \frac1n$$

Which converges as harmonic?

Comment: The harmonic series does not converge.

Comment: Oh no, I did it again...

Comment: If you switch the direction of $\leq$ you get a proof for divergence. What you wrote is not only useless, but false. And you forgot the sum signs all over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{1}{n +\ln n}\color{red}{\large \geq} \frac{1}{n+n} = \frac 1{2n}$$

$$n + \ln n \leq 2n \implies \frac 1{n + \ln} \geq \frac 1{2n}$$

We know the harmonic series *diverges*. Can you work now to show that your series also diverges?

Comment: A very important difference between this and what the OP has written: notice that the direction of the inequality is correct here, but uncorrect in the OP.

Comment: Oh my, that was silly of me. Thank you for that!

Comment: I can show it diverges because $\frac1{2n}$ diverges by integral test as $\int_1^\infty \frac1{2n} dn = \frac12 \frac1n dn = \frac12 \log(\infty) - log(1)$

Comment: Sure you can, but it is good to know that $\sum \dfrac 1{cn}$ diverges when $c$ is a nonzero constant, which is certainly provable by the integral test. $$\int_1^\infty \frac 1{cn} \,dn = \frac 1c \int_1^\infty \frac 1n \,dn \to \infty$$ Once proven, you can then use this knowledge in the future.